# How to handle stdin/stdout with dlv

Tags: go, delve

I am using Delve to debug and having issues with the best way to handle stdin/stdout.

The first problem is that I cannot read the console. I have a function that takes use onput from the console:

```
func readConsole() string {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    entry, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
    if err != nil {
        tlog.Fatal(fmt.Errorf("readConsole(): Error reading console input. %v", err))
    }
    entry = strings.Replace(entry, "\n", "", -1)
    return entry
}
```

The following "bad file descriptor" error is returned by ReadString():

```
F0208 21:03:56.574021  429026 configurator.go:81] readConsole(): Error reading console input. read /dev/stdin: bad file descriptor
```

The second problem is that fmt.Printf() works when I just run the app, but if I am stepping through source code fmt.Printf() does not display anything.

I get that dlv is competing for input and output via the console, but not sure how to manage the competing requirements.